# Drafts mysteriously deleted in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

All of the messages I had saved in my Drafts folder were deleted at a point when I wasn't even logged in to Outlook. I am using Outlook 2010. There were no other messages missing, and I was able to recover them, but how could that happen?

Comment: You've not given us enough information to definitively answer how this could happen. I suspect that even with as much information as you can provide, answers would be left to describe some possibilities, but never be able to say for sure. Such questions are not a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that your are actually connected to the server? I ask because drafts can exist in both an on-line and off-line state. If you are off line, and want to see your drafts next time you are off-line, just use the folder sysnc option. This option varies slightly between versions of Outlook, but for the most part you should be able to go to tools, send and recieve all folders. Likewise as in the newer version of Outlook 2010, you can right click on the folder in question, and go to the last tab which is the synchronization tab. From there you can set filters or criteria as to when this folder will sync. You might also look into having an OST file created, it acts as an offline replica of your online content, and then updates next time your on-line.